# Regex not working when using [.]+ instead of .+

Tags: regex, parsing

I want to parse a SQL select intruction. E.g. in JavaScript:

> a = 'select a, b from c, d where e'

> /((select[\s]*(.+))(from(.+))(where(.+)))/.exec(a)

This captures 'a, b' in group 3.

However, if there is a newline between 'a,' and 'b', the regex breaks because '.' does not capture newlines. Therefore, I tried switching the first (.+) for ([.\n\r]+) but it does not work. Even if there is no newline, ([.]+) cannot replace (.+):

> ((select[\s]*([.]+))(from(.+))(where(.+)))

Why not if [abc] means 'any of a, b or c'?

Comment: `[.]` is a dot, `.` is any character (except newlines)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `[.]` matches a literal `.`; using a character class is one way to change `.` from meaning "any character" to just matching itself (the other of course being a backslash).

If you want the set of characters matched by `.` to include newlines, you have to set "single-line" mode by adding the `/s` flag to the regex:

```
> "foo\nbar".match(/foo.bar/)
null
> "foo\nbar".match(/foo.bar/s)
[ 'foo\nbar', index: 0, input: 'foo\nbar', groups: undefined ]
```

While not relevant to your question, you often see the `/s` flag paired with the `/m` ("multi-line") flag which causes the anchors `^` and `$` to match internal newlines, not just the ends of the whole string:

```
> "foo\nbar".match(/foo$/)
null
> "foo\nbar".match(/foo$/m)
[ 'foo', index: 0, input: 'foo\nbar', groups: undefined ]
```